# Difference between Electron autoUpdater and electron-updater?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I was working through some autoUpdating changes on an app of mine, and I ran across the following

Electron Native - https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/auto-updater

Userland Electron Updater - https://www.electron.build/auto-update

It seems that these two APIs are very similar, but not identical. I can't seem to find any information on what differences there are between the two and which one is the "preferred" way to do seem less Electron updates?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.electron.build/auto-update
Differences between electron-updater and built-in autoUpdater¶
Dedicated release server is not required.
Code signature validation not only on macOS, but also on Windows.
All required metadata files and artifacts are produced and published automatically.
Download progress and staged rollouts supported on all platforms.
Different providers supported out of the box (GitHub Releases, Amazon S3, DigitalOcean Spaces, Keygen and generic HTTP(s) server).
You need only 2 lines of code to make it work.